# Simplified eqn for inductor charge for short timeframe?

Tags: inductor, charge

In a worked solution my professor has given me it says:

I(load) = Io(1-e^(t/time constant))

and I(load) = Io * (t/time constant) (for a short time period)

I don't understand how the second line can be true?

Comment: Whats the differential of (1-e^(t/time constant)) ? That gives you the slope of the curve, which will be OK to use for extrapolating over intervals over which the slope doesn't change much.

Comment: The initial gradient of \$(1-e^{-t/\tau})\$ for \$t \approx 0\$ is \$\frac{1}{\tau}\$, as is the gradient of \$\frac{t}{\tau}\$. In fact, a definition of \$\tau\$ is: the value of time where the exponential would reach the final value if the original rate of change were maintained.

Comment: It is because dI = V*dt/L for an inductor is fairly linear up to t=Tau/2 then exponentially decays to final load current.